# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, gradlew, google-play-services

Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.4,16.0.4], [16.3.0,16.3.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

```
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion   = "16.2.0"
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url 'http://maven.google.com' }
            jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
            google()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }

            configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy {
                    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0"
                    force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.2.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation('com.alibaba.android:ultraviewpager:1.0.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'com.littlechoc.cornerlabel:cornerlabel:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'

    // base library

    //slider
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0'

    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

    //   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.3'

    // implementation  'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'//:16.0.1'

    //implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.1'

    //   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'

    //   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'

    //***** implementation  'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.3.0'
    implementation 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    implementation 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'

    //permission asking module
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'

    //chat

    //implementation 'com.github.timigod:android-chat-ui:v0.1.3'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.1'

    //   implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.ernestoyaquello.stepperform:vertical-stepper-form:0.9.9'

    //multiple image picjer is not working

    //implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.12.0'

    // for experimental rx picker

    //implementation  'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.12.0'

    // If you have a problem with Glide, please use the same Glide version or simply open an issue

    // implementation  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'

    //annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.13'
    implementation 'com.yongchun:com.yongchun.imageselector:1.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.requery:requery:1.5.1'
    implementation 'io.requery:requery-android:1.5.1'

    // for android
    annotationProcessor 'io.requery:requery-processor:1.5.1'
    implementation 'rouchuan.viewpagerlayoutmanager:viewpagerlayoutmanager:2.0.18'
    implementation 'ja.burhanrashid52:photoeditor:0.1.1'
    implementation 'me.shaohui.advancedluban:library:1.3.5'

    //  implementation 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.6'

    //compile 'co.csadev.kwikpicker:1.0.0'

    //compile 'com.fxn769:pix:1.0.5'

    //compile 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0.4'

    //compile 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.0'

    //error free but dufiluct to use

    //compile 'com.github.searchy2:CustomImagePicker:2.1'

    //compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.2.2'

    //compile 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0.4'

    // Android plugin 3.0.0 or higher.

    //  implementation  'com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.8.6'

    //implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.2.1'

    //implementation 'co.csadev.kwikpicker:1.0.1'

    //   implementation 'co.csadev.kwikpicker:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'

    //compile 'me.iwf.photopicker:PhotoPicker:0.9.12@aar'

    ///image picker

    //

    // not working inside fragment

    //implementation 'com.myhexaville:smart-image-picker:1.0.4'

    //crash on click below libary

    //implementation 'com.fxn769:pix:1.0.5'

    //working with out minfiy not checked enled
    implementation 'com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.8.6'

    //banner ads
    implementation 'rouchuan.viewpagerlayoutmanager:viewpagerlayoutmanager:2.0.18'

    //replacing carouselview

    //implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0'

    //animated recycler view

    //implementation  "com.mlsdev.animatedrv:library:1.0.1"

    ///implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:2.0.1-rc1'

    //compile  'com.ramotion.cardslider:card-slider:0.2.0'

    //compile 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.6'

    //implementation  'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

    //annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'

    //implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'

    // implementation  'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.3'
    implementation 'moe.feng:MaterialStepperView:0.2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.2.8'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.0'

    //implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'

    // implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:rx:3.3.1'
    implementation('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3') {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.cleveroad:slidingtutorial:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.diegodobelo.expandingview:expanding-view:0.9.4'
    implementation 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.layer-net:step-indicator:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.flipboard:bottomsheet-core:1.5.3'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'

    //compile 'com.thefinestartist:finestwebview:1.2.7'

    //compile 'saschpe.android:customtabs:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:MaterialAbout:+'
    implementation 'com.github.halysongoncalves:pugnotification:1.8.1'

    //implementation  'com.tuenti.buttonmenu:library:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.rengwuxian:MaterialEditText:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.13'
    implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.beigirad:ZigzagView:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.linger1216:labelview:v1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation 'co.gofynd.library:gravity-view:1.0'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.3.0'
    //not workingimplementation 'com.github.florent37:viewtooltip:1.1.7'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chyrta:AndroidOnboarder:0.7'

    // Add the In-App Messaging dependency:
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i have same problem. you solve this issue?

Comment: same here sick of this

Answer (score 0):

I ust found this from https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/37 You can disable the check version of the Google Service Plugin

In the mean time, right after the apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of your build.gradle the following can be added to work around the issue.

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true